# why does it not work if I replace fadeIn/fadeOut with fadeToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two same jsfiddles , the latter replaced by fadeIn/fadeOut instead of fadeToggle.

**Just move with your mouse in and out fast, and keep the last moment on the yellow box and wait, the red element won't fade in.**

weird. anyone has an explanation for it?

**http://jsfiddle.net/q6d57/5/**  **(working)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".box1").mouseenter(function(){
        $('.box2').stop(true, false).fadeToggle(1500);
      });
      $(".box1").mouseleave(function(){
        $('.box2').stop(true, false).fadeToggle(1500);
      });
    });
```

and

**http://jsfiddle.net/q6d57/6/**  **(not working)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box1").mouseenter(function(){
    $('.box2').stop(true, false).fadeIn(3000);
  });
  $(".box1").mouseleave(function(){
    $('.box2').stop(true, false).fadeOut(3000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Both fiddles work fine for me using Chrome on Win7... What is supposed to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: Both are working for me...  Safari on a Mac.

Comment: both are working for me

Comment: Which one is not working for you

Comment: @Sico - Both are working in that they fade the element, just not the same way, as in one the stop function stops the animation, and it's continued, in the other it's stopped but does not continue, there are small differences.

Comment: @thenewseattle - In the source the methods seems to call the same function `.animate(props, speed, easing, callback);`

Comment: That is strange... and it seems to be working with fadeTo as well http://jsfiddle.net/q6d57/7/

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a definitive answer on this unless someone can dive deeper into the source, but there are indeed slight differences in how the `fade***` animation methods work with stop(), and I would think it's just some bug, and maybe filing a bug report will get you an answer.

Comment: Is it me or does it seem to work if you change jquery version to 2.0.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change jquery version to 2.0.2

Comment: I believe my answer is correct - but jQuery got smarter in 2.0.2. Nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

At first I was a bit baffled but I'm gonna venture an educated guess at this one after playing around in the chrome debugger while watching `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, & `fadeToggle` run it's course.

It seems as though what jQuery does with `fadeIn` is it checks the html element's `display` property. If the `display` is `none`, `fadeIn` fades the object in by setting the `display` to `block` and drifting the `opacity` from 0 to 1. So in your code, when you move your mouse away and back, it stops the `fadeOut` but since the `display` is still `block`, `fadeIn` fails to take affect.

However, `fadeToggle` is being a little smarter and checking `opacity` and not just the `display` property. Not only is it checking `opacity`, but probably keeps a flag on which fade was last executed (in or out) so it knows to do the other one.

This is all a bit of hearsay without digging into the jQuery library but I believe this is the only thing that could be happening after playing around in Chrome's awesome debugger ;).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using fadeIn/Out with non hidden elements.
That's why you need to add .hide() to make it work.

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q6d57/10/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box1").mouseenter(function(){
    $('.box2').stop(true, false).hide().fadeIn(3000);
  });
  $(".box1").mouseleave(function(){
    $('.box2').stop(true, false).hide().fadeOut(3000);
  });
});
```